# How to pass python variable output to fabric run

Tags: python, fabric

How to pass python variable output to fabric run

In below code i want to pass cmd2 variable to fabric run.

below is my code but it is not working :-

```
from fabric.api import *
import sys
import time
import getpass
ip = "host1"
user = raw_input('Please Enter user:')
password = getpass.getpass('Please Enter Password:')
env.hosts = ip
env.user = user
env.password = password
cmd2 = "touch 123.txt"
def commands():
    run('ls -l', shell=False)
    run('{}', shell=False).format(cmd2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error related to the use of `.format()`: you need to apply it to the string, not to the `run()` function. Here's the updated version of your `commands` function:

```
def commands():
    run('ls -l', shell=False)
    run('{}'.format(cmd2), shell=False)
```